# How can I play/pause a randomized mp3-file in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Within a vue-component I have a randomize button which loads a random mp3-file, so far so good. My problems is (edit: just one problem left):

**The second button does not pause/play the the file again as it should.**

Pls help, thx, Joel
template-Part:

```
<button  @click="randomize"></button>
<button  @click.prevent="chosenName.isPlaying ? pause(chosenName.file) : play(chosenName.file)">{{ chosenName.isPlaying ? '⏹️' : '▶️'}}</button>
```

script-part:

```
export default {
   data: function() {
       return {
        audioLogItems: [],
        chosenName: '',
        audios: [
        { 
            id: 'muscle-car',
            name: 'Margaret Dygas - Baton Signals',
            file: new Audio('https://saunahaus-test.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Margaret-Dygas-Baton-Signals.mp3'),
            isPlaying: false
        },
        {
        id: 'airplane-takeoff',
        name: 'Airplane Takeoff',
        file: new Audio('https://saunahaus-test.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Guitar-Treasure-Friends.mp3'),
        isPlaying: false
      }
    ]

   }
   },

   methods: {
   randomize () {
        var chosenNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.audios.length);
       //grab the name:
        var chosenName = this.audios[chosenNumber];
        this.pauseAll();

        chosenName.isPlaying = true;
        chosenName.file.play();
        chosenName.file.loop = true;
        this.audioLogItems.unshift({
            text: chosenName.name
        })

       },
   play (chosenName) {
        chosenName.isPlaying = true;
        chosenName.file.play();
        chosenName.loop = true;
   },
pauseAll() {
      this.audios.filter(audioItem=>audioItem.isPlaying).forEach(filteredAudioItem=>{
      filteredAudioItem.isPlaying = false;
      filteredAudioItem.loop = false;
      filteredAudioItem.file.pause();
    })
  },
    pause (chosenName) {
      chosenName.isPlaying = false;
       chosenName.file.pause();
    },

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did your problem get solved?

Comment: The First one yes, the second one not

Answer (score 0):

you need to stop the playing file before starting a new one.

One solution to achieve this could be a pauseAll method:

```
pauseAll() {
  this.audios.filter(audioItem=>audioItem.isPlaying).forEach(filteredAudioItem=>{
          filteredAudioItem.isPlaying = false;
          filteredAudioItem.loop = false;
          filteredAudioItem.file.pause();
        })
},
```

I created a jsfiddle.net for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/2n4y6xhb/

Comment: That solves the loop issue, great! Still thinking about how to toggle play pause on the other button...

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer in the vue-forum. Problem was the reference of the play and pause functions in the button. Adding a toggle-function with .this.play/pause did the trick:

```js
toggle () {
      return this.activeAudio.isPlaying ? this.pause() : this.play()
    },
```

```html
<button v-if="activeAudio" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  
@click.prevent="toggle">
{{ activeAudio.isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play' }}
</button>
```

Also set v-if to bypass the button complaining about “activeAudio” being null if there hasn't been a randomize-click/file call yet. Thank you sherlockmac again for the solution .